# Convert string data to numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a long list of string values from a website through selenium. These string values are numbers, so I would like to transform them into numbers into python. The first part of my code is:

```
find_string_values=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("string")
```

Now in my console I see al the numerical data stored as string. How can I convert them?

Comment: add code trials and errors to your question

Comment: So you see them, ok. And how are the data stored? Numpy array, list, tuple, dict, pandas dataframe...? Please tell everything important, at best including code with your own attempt. See also [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you can split, then convert each element to an int.

```
string_of_numbers = "12234 56223 55 3212 56 234"

split_list = string_of_numbers.split()

converted_list = [ int(x) for x in split_list ]
```

If there's decimals:

```
string_of_numbers = "12234.34 56223 55 3212 56 234"

split_list = string_of_numbers.split()

converted_list = [ float(x) for x in split_list ]
```